# fuzzy wuzzy WRatio for Uppercase detection

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I need help in figuring out why

```
fuzz.WRatio('Māne', 'mane', force_ascii=True) => 75%
```

and also

```
fuzz.WRatio('Māne', 'Mane', force_ascii=True) => 75%
```

I would expect the force_ascii parameter to enforce more accuracy.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two arguments `force_ascii` and `full_process` when working with `fuzz.WRatio` in fuzzywuzzy, that are both True by default. They are both used for preprocessing the strings (force_ascii is only used when full_process is True aswell and otherwise ignored).

1) When using `force_ascii=False, full_process=False`
The strings are not changed before matching them so e.g. uppercase/lowercase matters.

2) When using `force_ascii=False, full_process=True`
All non alphanumeric characters in the strings are replaced with a whitespace, the strings are lowercased and whitespaces from beginning and end are trimmed. So for example
"Mäne!" -> "Mäne " -> "mäne " -> "mäne"

2) When using `force_ascii=True, full_process=True`
This does the same as 2) but removes all non ascii characters beforehand. So for example
"Mäne!" -> "Mne!" -> "Mne " -> "mne " -> "mne"

I do not really think that it is a good thing that `force_ascii` defaults to true, since I personally do not really want this behaviour in 99% of the cases, but most people using fuzzywuzzy are not even aware of this behaviour.
Beside this it appears to have a bug, since e.g

```py
> utils.full_process("ā", force_ascii=True)
'ā'
```

while it is clearly no ascii character and should therefore return an empty string.

In your case where you want it to consider any difference between the two strings you should call

```py
> fuzz.WRatio('Māne', 'mane', full_process=False)
50
> fuzz.WRatio('Māne', 'Mane', full_process=False)
75
```

Comment: I did understand your answer but I do not understand all the nuances of the module. For instance fuzz.WRatio('Mane', 'manēre', full_process=False) = 60 but fuzz.WRatio('Mane', 'māne', full_process=False) = 50. Isn't there more distance in the first comparison, thus score should be lower? Is there a documentation for the lay man out there besides the code itself? THis is perhaps another question. Thanks.

Comment: could you ask a second question about this? The reason for this has nothing to do with the preprocessing